# PlacepickerJS on init get place.address_components

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [jquery-placepicker](http://benignware.github.io/jquery-placepicker/) to append into different input hiddens the address details.

Sadly, on init with a default address without submiting, the placepicker returns me only the `place.geometry.location.lng()` and `place.geometry.location.lat()` informations, not the `place.address_components`

```
$("#inputAddress").placepicker({
    map: $('#map').get(0),
    placeChanged: function (place) {
        $('#input_address_lng').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
        $('#input_address_lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());

        // reset fields
        $('#input_address_num').val('');
        $('#input_address_rue').val('');
        $('#input_address_ville').val('');
        $('#input_address_codepays').val('');
        $('#input_address_cp').val('');

        if (place.address_components) {
            updateAddressForm(place.address_components);
        }
    }
});

function updateAddressForm(address) {
$.each(address, function (index, value) {
    if (value.types[0] == 'street_number') {
        $('#input_address_num').val(value.long_name);
    } else if (value.types[0] == 'route') {
        $('#input_address_rue').val(value.long_name);
    } else if (value.types[0] == 'locality') {
        $('#input_address_ville').val(value.long_name);
    } else if (value.types[0] == 'postal_code') {
        $('#input_address_cp').val(value.long_name);
    } else if (value.types[0] == 'country') {
        $('#input_address_codepays').val(value.short_name);
    }
});
}
```

I tried this solution which allows me to retrieve detailed address :

```
$("#inputAddress").placepicker({
    map: $('#map').get(0),
    placeChanged: function (place) {
        $('#input_address_lng').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
        $('#input_address_lat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());

        // reset fields
        $('#input_address_num').val('');
        $('#input_address_rue').val('');
        $('#input_address_ville').val('');
        $('#input_address_codepays').val('');
        $('#input_address_cp').val('');

        if (place.address_components) {
            updateAddressForm(place.address_components);
        } else {

            var request = {
                placeId: place.place_id
            };

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.getDetails(request, callback);

            function callback(place, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    updateAddressForm(place.address_components);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but now the google map does not work anymore...

Any idea?

Thx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling  [Dev tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to see the exact issue you are experiencing. You might want to look at the sample implementation provided by Google - [Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

[image]

> This example captures selected address components from the Google Places database into an address form. The selection of address components in this example is typical. You may need to adjust it to align with postal addresses of each country.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <style>
      #locationField, #controls {
        position: relative;
        width: 480px;
      }
      #autocomplete {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 99%;
      }
      .label {
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100px;
        color: #303030;
      }
      #address {
        border: 1px solid #000090;
        background-color: #f0f0ff;
        width: 480px;
        padding-right: 2px;
      }
      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }
      .field {
        width: 99%;
      }
      .slimField {
        width: 80px;
      }
      .wideField {
        width: 200px;
      }
      #locationField {
        height: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="locationField">
      <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
             onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
    </div>

    <table id="address">
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field" id="street_number"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2"><input class="field" id="route"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
             You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
             https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
        -->
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field" id="locality"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField"><input class="field"
              id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input></td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField"><input class="field" id="postal_code"
              disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3"><input class="field"
              id="country" disabled="true"></input></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
      // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

      function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});

        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }

      function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }

      // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
      // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.